# Add user email addresses separated by commas in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to add the selected users to a separate table from the list of all users. Similar to the Trello feature, just @ and tag their name. I have no idea what to write this function. Any ideas?

This is the form on my interface, and I do not know what to do next in the controller and the form block.

```html
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="group-add-members" role="tabpanel">
    <div class="users-manage" data-filter-list="form-group-users">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <textarea class="form-control col" name="group-description"
                          placeholder="Add users by email, each email separated by 
                          commas&#10;e.g: matt@.edu.com, joe@edu.com" rows="3">
                </textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="col">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button">
                        <i class="fad fa-user-plus"></i>Add</button>
                    <span> &ensp; or &ensp; </span>
                </div>
                <div class="d-none d-md-block col-4 col-lg-5 text-right">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row align-items-center mt-2">
                <div class="d-block d-md-none d-sm-block ml-2">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <h6>Member info</h6>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="table-responsive mt-3">
                <table class="stripe" id="example" style="width:100%">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th class="text-left">Full name</th>
                        <th class="text-left">Email</th>
                        <th class="text-left">Student ID</th>\
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="text-left">My name</td>
                        <td class="text-left">qnv164@edu.com</td>
                        <td class="text-left">123456789</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#"><span class="ic-dark"><i class="fad fa-trash-alt"></i></span></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th class="text-left">Full name</th>
                        <th class="text-left">Email</th>
                        <th class="text-left">Student ID</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
            </div>
            <!-- end div table responsive -->
        </div>
        <!-- end div row -->
    </div>
</div>
{{ profile->description ?? 'Not Available' }}
```

Comment: how about something different like: https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage#multi-select-boxes-pillbox